# Unexpected output when printing an array

Tags: python

I'm trying to find the minimum of an array and print it. Easy right? Apparently not. My code:

```
array = generateAtoms(num)
arrayPoints, vArraySum = moveMolecule(array, numSteps=steps)
plotSetUp(arrayPoints)
#print vArraySum
print min(vArraySum), " kJ/mol is the minimum potential achieved"
```

I expect my answer to be in the range of -0.19. If I don't print the print statement above, my output is around 9,000,000 kJ/mol. If I do print it, my print statement is as expected.

Here is an example of `vArraySum` (if I run the print):

```
[88824.74221919772, 18198.301666484836, 3531.2537391848105, 3531.2537391848105, 
3531.2537391848105, 16.432760713742276, -0.09559319207145775, -0.09559319207145775, 
-0.19379982167330503, -0.19379982167330503, -0.19379982167330503, -0.19379982167330503, 
-0.19379982167330503, -0.19379982167330503, -0.19379982167330503, -0.19379982167330503, 
-0.19379982167330503, -0.19379982167330503, -0.19379982167330503, -0.19379982167330503]
```

How is my output changing when I "observe" it (using print)? I'm at a complete loss. To add, the 9 million number is not the same number every time, but is around 9 million each time.

Edit2:

```
def moveMolecule(array, numSteps):
# Moves molecules in random directions by adding random array
# Will not move points if potential of system increases
points = []
vArray = []
vArraySum = []
progress = 0

points.append(array)
for i in range(numSteps):
    addArray = np.random.uniform(low=-0.2, high=0.2, size=(num,3))
    if sumV(np.add(array, addArray)) < sumV(array):
        array = np.add(array, addArray)
    else: 
        array = array
    points.append(array)
    vArray.append(vArrays(array))
    vArraySum.append(sumV(array))

    # Updates progress bar
    progress = updateProgressBar(progress, i, numSteps)

plotV(points, vArray)

return points, vArraySum
```

Edit3:

```
def functionV(r):
# Function to calculate LJ potential
return ((4 * _e) * (((_d / r) ** 12) - ((_d / r) ** 6)))


def sumV(array):
# Uses NN search to calculate sum of potential of system
V = []

# Performs NN search to collect nearby radii
points = NNSearchSetUp(array)

radius  = NNSearch(points)

# Calculate potential for NNs
for r in radius:
    V.append(functionV(r))
return sum(V)
```

Comment: Can you add more information about your input and the logic behind your code, also you expected output? Actually i don't see anything wrong in your code.

Comment: Cannot reproduce.

Comment: "Please let me know if there's any other information you'd like me to add". How about the functions that your code uses? How do you expect anyone to know why `generateAtoms()`, `moveMolecule` and/or `plotSetUp` doesn't work as you expect when you keep those definitions secret? Please give a [mcve].

Comment: Would you mind giving your question a descriptive, useful title instead of a funny one?

Comment: @selbie Is _print array weirdness_ really a better title than the orignal?

Comment: @leaf - You may edit it yourself or suggest something you'd like me to change it to.

Comment: @selbie  I sort of can't. I'd have to make another suggested edit, and I'm not sure a title only edit would be approved.

Comment: @leaf - Just tell me what you want the title to be in the comment box and I will change it.

Comment: @selbie Well I went ahead and suggested an edit now. _Opps_. But what about _unexpected output when printing an array_? I know It's still not a great title, but there really isn't a "good" title you can give this question. It's a start. Until the OP adds more context, you can't really make give the question a "good" title.

Comment: If `vArraySum` is an array of objects from a class which implements its own `__str__()` then the act of printing it could potentially modify it, though it would be rather perverse to write such a class. An array of floats isn't modified by printing it. If that is what you think is happening, then you are mistaken.

Comment: Sorry for the title. I can change it.

Comment: I've showed it to a few friends and they're just as completely jazzed about it as I am

Comment: And Jonn, my code is 1,000 lines. I can attach the functions but screenshots might be easier

Comment: @MonicaRasmussen don't do screen shots. Add the code _verbatim_.

Comment: If all you can offer is either a few mysterious lines full of unknown references or an entire 1000-line program, you are not ready to ask a question on this site.

Comment: What is the *type* of `vArraySum`, and the objects it contains? In any event -- you need to make a *minimal* reproducible example. It is unlikely that those 1000 lines are needed.

Comment: Also yea I get it, trust me, I completely understand my code isn't great. I'm pretty new. Positivity would be appreciated greatly. Sorry if my punny title bothered you.

Comment: For example, if the elements in `vArraySum` are really strings, then `min()` will return the string which is minimal in lex-order, not numerical order.

Comment: @John, I don't believe they are strings? I appended an array with floats, I believe. But thank you, I will spend some time going through that to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. vArraySum is a numpy array. Must not play nice with min? Thank you @John. Casting the array as floats fixed the issue

Comment: `numpy` has a function called `np.min()` which should also work. I'm not quite sure what the issue with `min()` since I would think that it should work.